# Converting a pytorch model to nn.Module for exporting to onnx for lens studio

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to convert pix2pix to a pb or onnx that can run in Lens Studio. Lens studio has strict requirements for the models. I am trying to export this pytorch model to onnx using [this guide provided by lens studio.](https://lensstudio.snapchat.com/guides/machine-learning/ml-frameworks/export-from-pytorch/) **The issue is the pytorch model [found here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/pix2pix.ipynb) uses its own base class, when in the example it uses Module.nn**, and therefore doesnt have methods/variables that the `torch.onnx.export` function needs to run. So far Ive run into its missing a variable called `training` and a method called `train`

**Would it be worth it to try to modify the base model, or should I try to build it from scratch using nn.Module? Is there a way to make the pix2pix model inherit from both the abstract base class and nn.module?** Am I not understanding the situation? The reason why I want to do it using the lens studio tutorial is because I have gotten it to export onnx different ways but Lens Studio wont accept those for various reasons.

Also this is my first time asking a SO question (after 6 years of coding), let me know if I make any mistakes and I can correct them. Thank you.

This is the important code from the tutorial creating a pytorch model for Lens Studio:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=1, 
                               kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer(x)
        out = nn.functional.interpolate(out, scale_factor=2, 
                                        mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
        out = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=1)
        return out
```

I'm not going to include all the code from the pytorch model bc its large, but the beginning of the baseModel.py is

```
import os
import torch
from collections import OrderedDict
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from . import networks


class BaseModel(ABC):
    """This class is an abstract base class (ABC) for models.
    To create a subclass, you need to implement the following five functions:
        -- <__init__>:                      initialize the class; first call BaseModel.__init__(self, opt).
        -- <set_input>:                     unpack data from dataset and apply preprocessing.
        -- <forward>:                       produce intermediate results.
        -- <optimize_parameters>:           calculate losses, gradients, and update network weights.
        -- <modify_commandline_options>:    (optionally) add model-specific options and set default options.
    """

    def __init__(self, opt):
        """Initialize the BaseModel class.

        Parameters:
            opt (Option class)-- stores all the experiment flags; needs to be a subclass of BaseOptions

        When creating your custom class, you need to implement your own initialization.
        In this function, you should first call <BaseModel.__init__(self, opt)>
        Then, you need to define four lists:
            -- self.loss_names (str list):          specify the training losses that you want to plot and save.
            -- self.model_names (str list):         define networks used in our training.
            -- self.visual_names (str list):        specify the images that you want to display and save.
            -- self.optimizers (optimizer list):    define and initialize optimizers. You can define one optimizer for each network. If two networks are updated at the same time, you can use itertools.chain to group them. See cycle_gan_model.py for an example.
        """
        self.opt = opt
        self.gpu_ids = opt.gpu_ids
        self.isTrain = opt.isTrain
        self.device = torch.device('cuda:{}'.format(self.gpu_ids[0])) if self.gpu_ids else torch.device('cpu')  # get device name: CPU or GPU
        self.save_dir = os.path.join(opt.checkpoints_dir, opt.name)  # save all the checkpoints to save_dir
        if opt.preprocess != 'scale_width':  # with [scale_width], input images might have different sizes, which hurts the performance of cudnn.benchmark.
            torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
        self.loss_names = []
        self.model_names = []
        self.visual_names = []
        self.optimizers = []
        self.image_paths = []
        self.metric = 0  # used for learning rate policy 'plateau'
```

and for pix2pix_model.py

```
import torch
from .base_model import BaseModel
from . import networks


class Pix2PixModel(BaseModel):
    """ This class implements the pix2pix model, for learning a mapping from input images to output images given paired data.

    The model training requires '--dataset_mode aligned' dataset.
    By default, it uses a '--netG unet256' U-Net generator,
    a '--netD basic' discriminator (PatchGAN),
    and a '--gan_mode' vanilla GAN loss (the cross-entropy objective used in the orignal GAN paper).

    pix2pix paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004.pdf
    """
    @staticmethod
    def modify_commandline_options(parser, is_train=True):
        """Add new dataset-specific options, and rewrite default values for existing options.

        Parameters:
            parser          -- original option parser
            is_train (bool) -- whether training phase or test phase. You can use this flag to add training-specific or test-specific options.

        Returns:
            the modified parser.

        For pix2pix, we do not use image buffer
        The training objective is: GAN Loss + lambda_L1 * ||G(A)-B||_1
        By default, we use vanilla GAN loss, UNet with batchnorm, and aligned datasets.
        """
        # changing the default values to match the pix2pix paper (https://phillipi.github.io/pix2pix/)
        parser.set_defaults(norm='batch', netG='unet_256', dataset_mode='aligned')
        if is_train:
            parser.set_defaults(pool_size=0, gan_mode='vanilla')
            parser.add_argument('--lambda_L1', type=float, default=100.0, help='weight for L1 loss')

        return parser

    def __init__(self, opt):
        """Initialize the pix2pix class.

        Parameters:
            opt (Option class)-- stores all the experiment flags; needs to be a subclass of BaseOptions
        """
```

(Also sidenote if you see this and it looks like no easy way out let me know, I know what its like seeing someone getting started in something who goes in to deep too early on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely have your model inherit from both the base class and `torch.nn.Module` (python allows multiple inheritance). However you should take care about the conflicts if both inherited class have functions with identical names (I can see at least one : their base provide the `eval` function and so to nn.module).

However since you do not need the CycleGan, and a lot of the code is compatibility with their training environment, you'd probably better just re-implement the pix2pix. Just steal the code, have it inherit from nn.Module, copy-paste useful/mandatory functions from the base class, and have everything translated into clean pytorch code. You already have the forward function (which is the only requirement for a pytorch module).

All the subnetworks they use (like the resnet blocks) seem to inherit from `nn.Module` already so there is nothing to change here (double check that though)